# I'm trying to add a background image at header, why won't it show up?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I've been trying to add a background image to the 'header' tag for a while now. I'm sure the problem is probably really simple and I have checked the names of my files and path, but I still can't find a solution

Does anyone know what the problem is?
Here is the html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
```

Here is the css:

```
header{
    width: 100%; height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('../img/sciencecool.jpeg');
}
```

I would really appreciate a response, thank you.

Comment: show the HTML too. Just a guess, change `header` to `.header`?

Comment: Where is the header element in the HTML you shared?

Comment: If you want help you'll need to be as specific as possible - include example, code snippets, and so on

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a class *.header* or the html *header* tag? Have you checked if the image and Css path are correct?

Answer (score 0):

in html at first write :

in css write :
.header {
background-image : url
}